# Save result in new table SQL

Tags: sql

How can I save the data into a new table?

```
SELECT
      produse.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F,
      stoc.CANTITATE,
      produse.PRET,
      produse.VALUTA,
      stare.STARE
FROM clase
JOIN produse ON produse.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN furnizori ON produse.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID
JOIN stoc ON stoc.ID_PRODUS = produse.ID
JOIN stare ON stare.ID = stoc.ID_STARE;
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using, you've already got product specific answer(s).

Comment: Is the new table already existing, or do you expect it to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For Oracle) Use a `create table as` statement(aka CTAS statement):

```
create table new_table as 
your_select;
```

See some examples [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/CTAS).

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can use SELECT INTO

```
SELECT
      produse.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F,
      stoc.CANTITATE,
      produse.PRET,
      produse.VALUTA,
      stare.STARE
INTO NewTable
FROM clase
JOIN produse ON produse.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN furnizori ON produse.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID
JOIN stoc ON stoc.ID_PRODUS = produse.ID
JOIN stare ON stare.ID = stoc.ID_STARE;
```

Comment: @jarlh True...  I've specified the dbms.  Thanks.